# How to prevent axis rescale when trace hidden in plotly?

Tags: plotly, scatter-plot

In figures with multiple traces, when the user hides a trace it causes the x,y axes to rescale their range based on the trace(s) still visible.

How to prevent this rescale ?

Answer (score 0):

You must fix the axis range :

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_range=fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False).layout.xaxis.range,
    yaxis_range=fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False).layout.yaxis.range,
)
```